# show 4 digits after a decimal without rounding the values

Tags: php

I have some decimal values like below

```
6.8199999999999
5.245
0.00147
18.333398
7.1
```

I need to show these numbers in 4 digits after the decimal without rounding as below

```
6.8199
5.2450
0.0014
18.3333
7.1000
```

I tried to use `number_format()` in php but it rounds the values

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: You could use something like `if(strpos('.', $number) !== false){ $number = substr($number, 0, strpos('.', $number) + 4) }`. That might need to be +5, not sure off the top of my head. Or you could just truncate the float after 4 places like `floor($number * 10000) / 10000;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$number = 6.8199999999999;
echo $number =  sprintf('%.4f', floor($number*10000*($number>0?1:-1))/10000*($number>0?1:-1));
```

Output:

```
6.8199
```

Comment: Great.. it works but there is a small problem when it domes to negative values. when i try to use `$number = -6.8199999999999;` it gives me`-6.8200`. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @LiveEn Now it should work! You just need to know the tricks :D

Comment: Another happy ending.